# Use a custom thumbnail for (QuickTime) videos without distorting it

Tags: finder, video, quicktime

I'd like to use a certain frame of a video as the thumbnail. To do it I right-clicked on that video file in Finder and opened its information. Then I selected the QuickTime-Player icon and copy-pasted the custom thumbnail.

While that thumbnail did change into the one I wanted to use, it was compressed from its (original) rectangular size to a square and now obviously looks very distorted. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Use preview to crop the image to a square and *THEN* paste it into the get-info window

Comment: Is that really the only way? Because I'd prefer it a lot if I can use the the whole frame as the thumbnail and not only part of it.

Comment: If you want the whole frame you may have to then ADD a bar at top or bottom (or both) to then make the picture square. Either way you look at it you have to either subtract from one or both sides or add to the top, bottom or both. Icons are generally square so if you don't paste a square picture into that window it gets squished in one direction to make it fit.